# listdata.svc does not respond in VS

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I am trying to add list.svc to a project in VS 2010. Even though, the path http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc is accessible through internet browsers, when I attempt to add service to my project, I get the error message below.

I recently changed the authentication method of my site to Claim Based Authentication, would that cause this error?

> There was an error downloading 'http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc'.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc'.
>   An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Update:

If I go to http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc in my machine, it works.

However, if I go to http://server/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc on the server, it says on Fiddler that  "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Could you help me with how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Q: Did you tried to add the reference via WCF Service Reference? Any load balancers or proxy settings in your browser?

Comment: yes I am trying to add it via Add Service Reference. No loadbalancer or proxy on my browser...

Comment: Ok, so you say it works in browser (same machine, same address), but doing same from VS, get the error?
Try using Fiddler while you add reference from VS 2010, see if your call passes properly. Try adding that url to your secure zone (Intranet, by example) and make sure your settings in the IIS  - for the Web Application you are using WINDOWS.

Comment: I have updated the question, it works on my local browser, but it does not on the web browser in server. strange. In VS add, it still get same error stated in the question. Adding site to secure zone did not make difference..

Comment: Does browing the site using the browser on the server work. If not then it's probably LoopbackCheck that bides you.

Comment: @PerJakobsen no it is not working.how could I sort that then?

Comment: it happened after I migrated my application to Claim based authentication model..

Comment: Try to have a look at [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) it has two workarounds for Loopback check I recommend Method 1 for production and Method 2 for development

Comment: Now it times out...

Comment: it is not working via browsers both in server and local, if I am not logged into site. I go to site and login, then try to call listdata.svc in browser it works. However, then i try to add the service as reference, it throws gateway time out. do you think that it works as designed?

Comment: This is clearly credentials error. But how am I supposed to provide credentials when adding the service to project?

Comment: Yes, in VS 2010 when adding the reference you will be asked to provide credentials. Unless there is an issue with your installation of Visual Studio there should be no issues. Tried rebooting to clear caching?? Did u disabled the Loopback check (if you're using FQDN with SP locally)?